# My internet connection seems do drop occasionally. How to debug it to identify the issue?

Tags: linux, networking

Sometimes the browser gives a DNS connection error and when I look at the connection stats it all has gone to 0.

[image]

How can I investigate what's the problem?
(where to look, what to do)

I'm using `Debian GNU/Linux 10`. The connection is wifi.

And the network is configured using the KDE settings.

```
KDE Frameworks 5.54.0
Qt 5.11.3 (built against 5.11.3)
The xcb windowing system
```

Comment: Have you tried a different DNS resolution service, e.g., Cloudflare or Google?

Comment: Start with modem logs.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm already using Google DNS

Comment: @BlindSpots I changed modem recently, so that shouldn't be it, but how do I access those?

Comment: There is usually an admin interface.  You log in using the gateway address.  The logs can show you a lot of things like wifi changing channels.